# Can not get the paragraph element to fade transition when it appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

This question has been edited and simplified again. I created a set of buttons when you hover over one of those buttons, a descriptive paragraph appears underneath. It works for the most part but I am trying to get the paragraph to slide up and fade in when it appears on hover, and then on mouse out, slide back down and fade out. I can't seem to get the fade part of the animation to work. That is what I am having trouble with mainly.

Also, could the Jquery code be simplified? If not that is fine. Thank you in advance.

```js
$('#web').hover(function(){
  $('#web-blurp').toggleClass('show-blurp');
});

$('#design').hover(function(){
  $('#design-blurp').toggleClass('show-blurp');
});

$('#film').hover(function(){
  $('#film-blurp').toggleClass('show-blurp');
});

$('#marketing').hover(function(){
  $('#marketing-blurp').toggleClass('show-blurp');
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: black;  
}

.hero-content {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20% auto;
}

.hero-content li {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .8s ease;
}

.hero-content a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.hero-content a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero-content span {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 40% 0;
 font-family: Sans-Serif; 
 text-transform: uppercase; 
 font-size: 1.2em;
 font-weight: 400; 
 color: blue;
  
}

.feat-blurp {
  width: 44%;
  margin: -300px auto 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.hide-blurp {
  display: none; 
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}

.show-blurp {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
  animation-name: blurp-up;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes blurp-up {
  from{ transform: translateY(50px)}
  to{ transform: translateY(0)}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="hero-content">
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-one" id="web">
     <span>button 1</span>
    </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-two" id="design">
      <span>button 2</span>
    </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-three" id="film">
      <span>button 3</span> 
    </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-four" id="marketing">
      <span>button 4</span>
    </a></li>
    </ul>

<div class="feat-blurp">
  <p id="web-blurp" class="hide-blurp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
  <p id="design-blurp" class="hide-blurp">nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat </p>
  <p id="film-blurp" class="hide-blurp">reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p id="marketing-blurp" class="hide-blurp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I answered the first part of my question. I did not realize you can use keyframes for the opacity attribute. Adding an opacity keyframe animation was the solution to the problem.

```js
$('#web').hover(function(){
  $('#web-blurp').toggleClass('show-blurp');
});

$('#design').hover(function(){
  $('#design-blurp').toggleClass('show-blurp');
});

$('#film').hover(function(){
  $('#film-blurp').toggleClass('show-blurp');
});

$('#marketing').hover(function(){
  $('#marketing-blurp').toggleClass('show-blurp');
});
```

```css
    body{
  background-color: black;  
}

.hero-content {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20% auto;
}

.hero-content li {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .8s ease;
}

.hero-content a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.hero-content a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero-content span {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 40% 0;
 font-family: Sans-Serif; 
 text-transform: uppercase; 
 font-size: 1.2em;
 font-weight: 400; 
 color: blue;
  
}

.feat-blurp {
  width: 44%;
  margin: -300px auto 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.hide-blurp {
  display: none; 
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
}

.show-blurp {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;
  animation-name: blurp-up, blurp-fade; /*//add opacity animations//*/
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes blurp-up {
  from{ transform: translateY(50px)}
  to{ transform: translateY(0)}
}
/*//keyframes can be used for opacity as well//*/
@keyframes blurp-fade {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="hero-content">
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-one" id="web">
     <span>button 1</span>
    </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-two" id="design">
      <span>button 2</span>
    </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-three" id="film">
      <span>button 3</span> 
    </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="feat-btn box-four" id="marketing">
      <span>button 4</span>
    </a></li>
    </ul>

<div class="feat-blurp">
  <p id="web-blurp" class="hide-blurp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
  <p id="design-blurp" class="hide-blurp">nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat </p>
  <p id="film-blurp" class="hide-blurp">reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p id="marketing-blurp" class="hide-blurp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
</div>
```